# Filtering input data

Tags: php

I created a function that filters data and I want to know if it's fully secure to filter user input data.

```
function user_input_data($data,$options) {
    $output = null;
    $error_msg = "";
    $check_length = false;
    $options_fetch = array(
    @$length_max = $options["length_max"],
    @$length_min = $options["length_min"],
    $data_type = $options["data_type"],
    );

    if($length_min && $length_max) {
        $check_length = true;
    }

    if($data_type == "only_letters") {

        if (preg_match('/^[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z]+\h?[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z]*$/u', $data)) {
             $output = $data;
        }else{
            $output = false;
        }
    }

    if($data_type == "only_letters_numbers") {

        if (preg_match('/^[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9]+\h?[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9]*$/u', $data)) {                    
            $output = $data;     
        }else{
            $output = false;
        }
    }          

    if($data_type == "string") {
        $output = htmlspecialchars($data,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8",true);
    }
    if($data_type == "text") {
        $output = strip_tags($data);
    }
    if($data_type == "integer") {
        if(filter_var($data,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
            $output = $data;
        }
    }
    if($data_type == "float") {
        if(filter_var($data,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)) {
            $output = $data;
        }
    }
    if($data_type == "boolean") {
        if(filter_var($data,FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) {
            $output = $data;
        }
    }
    if($data_type == "email") {
        if(filter_var($data,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $output = $data;
        }
    }
    if($data_type == "url") {
        if(filter_var($data,FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            $output = $data;
        }
    }
    if($data_type == "ip") {
        if(filter_var($data,FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
            $output = $data;
        }
    }
    if($data_type == "array") {
        if(is_array($data)) {
            $data = array_map("htmlspecialchars",$data);
            $output = $data;
        }
    }
    if($data_type == "file_directory") {
        if(file_exists($data)) {
            $output = basename($data);
        }
    }
    if($output) {

    if($check_length) {

        if( ( ( mb_strlen($output) >= $length_min ) && ( mb_strlen($output) <= $length_max ) ) === false) {
            $output = false;
        }
    }
    return $output;

    }
}

// call function 
$password = user_input_data(
    $_POST["password"],
    array(
        "length_min" => 8, "length_max" => 24 ,"data_type" => "string"
    )
);
```

Comment: Frankly, this function has very little to do with security and by no means should be relied upon.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  I created this function  for filter user input data only. In my question I ask if it is completely safe in filtering user input data just no less and no more.

Comment: Nope, it is not safe

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank you. but really I don't way if I want to know if user input just contain letters I call function like this `$var = user_input_data($POST['var'],array("data_type" => "only_letters"))` so if user input data contain numbers or characters it return false

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should use a configuration array like this:

```
 $config = [
      ip => FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,
      email=> FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
 ]
```

and simplify the code like this:

```
if(in_array($config, $data_type)) {
     if($filter_VAR($data, $config[$data_type]) {
          $output = $data;
     }
}
```

2. In your code, length is checked only if both min and max are set. Is it the expected behavior? In some cases, only min or max checks are required.
3. Generally, you should avoid repeating code, in favor of calling functions. This makes it more readable. Plus, you can create test cases for small functions with predictable results, rather that a big complicated thing.
4. With security I have no idea what this function is designed to protect against.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I think all of you understood me wrong. I designed this function for only filter user input data to avoid repeating. and I ask if it's good and I think they need some Improvements

Comment: @MouradKaroudi there you are. I suggested 3 areas where you can improve your code. Still, it is unclear what did you want to achieve in security area.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply and your time.
I use this function in my website to filter form inputs data like a Register form had input called `full_name` so I want this input accept only letters english and arabic so I use this function to do that for me.
what I want is to know if this function good to filter user input and secure my forms data

Comment: and look to my question I wrote ** it's fully secure to filter user input **